# SDWebimage - SDWebImageDownloader operation crash

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I have code, that downloads huge amount of images periodically. Code looks like this

```
func batchProductPicsDownload() {
        for product in products {
            SDWebImageDownloader.shared().downloadImage(with: URL(string: APIMode.BackofficeRoot + product.img_url), options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, bool) in
                if let image = image {
                    SDWebImageManager.shared().saveImage(toCache: image, for: URL(string: APIMode.BackofficeRoot + product.img_url))
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I get crash sometimes

[image]

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you please upload crash logs??

Comment: stack trace was empty